# Procedure called multiple times

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There's a bug in Neo4j where procedures that accept a nodelist get called multiple times. For example, algo.personalizedPageRank.stream gets called 8 times with a single node on a graph with 8 nodes:

```
MATCH p = (n)
CALL algo.personalizedPageRank.stream(nodes(p), 'Page', 'LINKS', {iterations:20, dampingFactor:0.85})
YIELD node, score
RETURN node,score order by score desc limit 20
```

Does anyone know how to work around this? One option is to group by node and use the SUM aggregation to find the personalized PageRank, but I'd rather not take the performance hit of having to call the algorithm once for each item in its input list.

Bug report (for reference):
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/10959

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug.

In Cypher, operations generate records/rows, and operations execute per record. This applies to nearly all clauses, including procedure calls. You can see this if you PROFILE the query: you have 8 rows resulting from your match, so the procedure will be called 8 times.

If you only want the procedure to execute only once, collect the nodes you want so you only have a single row with a node list, then call the query.

```
MATCH (n)
WITH collect(n) as nodes
CALL algo.personalizedPageRank.stream(nodes, 'Page', 'LINKS', {iterations:20, dampingFactor:0.85})
YIELD node, score
RETURN node,score order by score desc limit 20
```